# How to add Text View on Bottom of frame Layout using Java Code

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a `ViewFlipper` under which i have a `Linear Layout` and `Frame Layout`.

I am adding `imageViews` and `TextViews` in `Frame Layout` dynamically from `Java Class`

Right now its displaying `Text View` at the top of my Activity and `image View` after it.

I want to it first display `image View` and then `TextView`

[image]

I am sharing an excerpt from my `MainActivity.class`

```
    FrameLayout newsFrameLayout;

    newsFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.newsFrameLayout);

    FrameLayout n1= newsFrameLayout;

    ImageView imageView;


        imageView = new ImageView(this);
        n1.addView(imageView);

        titleTextView= new TextView(this);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(SlidingPaneLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, SlidingPaneLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   //   textViewParam.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM;

        n1.addView(titleTextView,textViewParam);
```

**Layout File**

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/newsSliderView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/newsLinearLayout">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/newsFrameLayout">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: Why not get rid of the `FrameLayout` and add your views to the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @karaokyo :Thanks for the reply..Either i put `Frame Layout` or remove it. The result is same

Answer (score 1):

Your views are added with the default gravity which is top. You need to specify the LayoutParams with which your want the views to be added. Tο get the textview to the bottom you do this:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
titleTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
n1.addView(titleTextView);
```

Comment: Its still displaying text on the top, and after adding `Match_Parent`, its now overlapping image and displaying only `Text`

Comment: I see your code updated and you are using RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout as I pointed out in my answer. What you are doing is using SlidingPaneLayout.LayoutParams constants on a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and then set that on a view that belongs to a FrameLayout. Does that make sence to you ?